# Is it worth removing unused CSS?

Tags: css, gulp

I am working on a simple web app with 2 other developers at college. We're using a couple of libraries, and packages. I am now trying to get our app ready for deployment, but have notices that it is quite slow. There are a lot of un-used CSS rules.

I tried manually going through compiled styles, searching for references and removing. But this is really tedious.

My question is:

- Is it worth removing unused CSS rules, or will the result be negligible?
- How is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Can you provide more details, on your site, and the code that you are using?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by worth. It wont do much for performance. But it will of course make the code more maintainable and readable. It is tedious work and in general i would only do it to the part of the code i am altering already.

Comment: It is worth it IMO. 1. It'll lower the size of the generated CSS files (it never hurts). 2. Your code will be easier to read and maintain in the long term by removing polluting code. 3. Remove redundancies and minimizing your selectors might help as well. 4. That's why preprocessor are for as well, managing your css in modules helps. 5. For further informations, read this great [article](https://www.labnol.org/internet/remove-unused-css/28635/) ;).

Comment: Yes, it is. The more unneeded stuff you can strip out the better. However, if you are using a library like Twitter Bootstrap you can use its CDN, if a user has already downloaded that version of the library from another site it will likely be cached, so won't even cost a request. Also, anything you strip out can add to the maintenance cost of the project, if you ever want to upgrade the library you'll have to do it all again. Lastly performance problems are most often due to large media files, check those first.

Comment: It's a shame that so many common libraries can just fill an app with bloat. Therefore it is important to treeshake your app, removing any unused code and assets. Minifying, bundling and effective caching will also help. Good luck with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Is it worth removing unused CSS rules?

I would say yes. To have any unused code in your production build is not cool .

However, unless something has gone very wrong, it is highly unlikley that your CSS is the reason for slow page loads, in fact the impact of loading a couple pages of unused css rules will be almost neglible. It's more likley to be images/ media, or maybe scripts.

You should probably investigate whats slowing down your page. Have a look in the network tab of your dev tools to start debugging why page load is slow, [Google Page Load Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) may also help. Have a look at [this blog series](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-radically-improve-your-website-performance-part-1-c728f4e5b08f), about speeding up your web apps too.

If you've not done so already you should probably minify and bundle your CSS and JS for production also.

---

## How to find and remove unused CSS rules

Removing unused CSS is a common task, and there are a lot of packages and tools out there which make it strait-forward. There are several options, going forwards:

#### 1. Manually remove unused CSS.

If your app is still quite small, this will probably be the easiest approach.

> 1. Open Chrome DevTools
> 2. Open the command menu with: cmd + shift + p
> 3. Type in “Coverage” and click on the “Show Coverage” option
> 4. Select a CSS file from the Coverage tab which will open the file up in the Sources tab

Source: [Google Developer, Chrome 59](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage)

#### 2. Use an online tool

There are tools out there, where you can just feed it a link to your site, and it will search and find unused CSS. The drawback here, is that this won't work locally.

- The best tool available it probably [UnusedCSS](https://unused-css.com/), however it only
  allows you to do one site for free.
- [UnCSS](https://uncss-online.com/) it totally free, but not as comprehensive.
- PureifyCSS is also good, and free.

#### 3. Automate CSS removal

[uncss](https://github.com/uncss/uncss) allows you to automate unused CSS removal, either at built-time, or complile-time. It also works with Grunt and Babel.

---

*A word of warning, some of your CSS might be detected as unused, when actually you are using it later on, such as when a request has finished loading. Be sure not to delete classes that are indirectly used.*

**Edit:**

> Be careful when using coverage for CSS usage, it considers media
>   queries, hover effects and others as useless since they're not applied
>   when loading your page

See also: https://css-tricks.com/unused/

Comment: Be careful when using coverage for CSS usage, it considers media queries, hover effects and others as useless since they're not applied when loading your page.

Comment: Good point, cheers, added it in. I think that [uncss](https://github.com/uncss/uncss), does let you specify multiple different media types, so that could still be an option.

Answer (score -1):

- Obviously, More css will load your app slow. To make your app more faster with same Css
  you can minify your css online and make it one line css. It will reduce your css file
  size.
- You can also do it for JS
- Also, Reduce your image size and load it from cache everytime

  To minify your css or JS go to https://www.minifier.org/