# How to copy only used CSS in developer tools

Tags: css, coding-style, developer-tools

I have CSS file with a lot of unused CSS lines.
And I want to clean CSS file but not manually.
In browser developer tools I can see (unused/used) CSS but I can't clean file and copy just used CSS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1dEj.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a CSS minifier tool is what you're looking for. There are online tools to help with this. Check out [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866495/is-it-worth-removing-unused-css) to see some options. I would recommend using this after you are done with development, otherwise it might make it harder to read.